# Awk - metacharacters

Tags: awk, regular-expression

> A regular expression consisting of a group of characters enclosed in brackets is called a *character class*; it matches any one of the enclosed characters. For example, `[AEIOU]` matches any of the characters `A`, `E`, `I`, `O`, or `U`.
>
> Ranges of characters can be abbreviated in a character class by using a hyphen. The character immediately to the left of the hyphen defines the beginning of the range; the character immediately to the right defines the end. Thus, `[0-9]` matches any digit, and `[a-zA-Z][0-9]` matches a letter followed by a digit. Without both a left and right operand, a hyphen in a character class denotes itself, so the character classes `[+-]` and `[-+]` match either a `+` or a `-`. The character class `[A-Za-z-]+` matches words that include hyphens.

What is the difference between `[+-]` and `[-+]`. It seems to me doing the same thing. And what does `[A-Za-z-]+` do?

```
$ awk '/[Y-Zy-z-]/' countries
India     1267 746  -Asia
$ awk '/[Y-Zy-z-]+/' countries
India     1267 746  -Asia
```

```
U         8649 275  Asia
Canada    3852 25   North America
China     3705 1032 Asia
USA       3615 237  North America
India     1267 746  -Asia
Mexico    762  78   North America
France    211  55   Europe
Japan     144  120  Asia
England   94   56   Europe
```

Or I tried

```
awk '/[^-]/' countries
```

and I expected nothing as an output.

```
$ awk '/[^-]/ countries
U         8649 275  Asia
Canada    3852 25   North America
China     3705 1032 Asia
USA       3615 237  North America
India     1267 746  -Asia
Mexico    762  78   North America
France    211  55   Europe
Japan     144  120  Asia
England   94   56   Europe
```

Comment: Why would you expect nothing as output in that last example? All lines contains at least one character that is not a dash.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The text refers to the fact that to match a dash, `-`, in a bracketed expression, `[...]`, the dash must occur first or last in the `[...]` (or just after an initial `^`, as in `[^-]` which matches any single character that is not a dash).

There is no difference between `[+-]` and `[-+]`.  Both matches either a `+` or a `-`.

The expression `[A-Za-z-]+` would match multiple (more than zero, due to the `+` after the `[...]`) ASCII characters from `A` to `Z` and from `a` to `z` *and dashes*.  The dash could also be put first as in `[-A-Za-z]+`.

Note that the internal two dashes in this expression denotes *ranges* whereas the last dash (or first in `[-A-Za-z]+`) denotes *a literal dash character* .

The `+` after `[...]` modifies the expression so that it matches one or more characters from within the `[...]`.  Without the `+`, the expression would match exactly one character, and not a word with optional dashes.

---

The second screenshot shows that you are matching `[Y-Zy-z-]` and `[Y-Zy-z-]+` against some data.

You get the same result for both patterns since that's the only line that contains one or more character from the set `YZyz-`.  The character that matches is the `-` character in the substring `-Asia`.

Then you tried with `[^-]`.  This matches on *all* lines, as all lines contains some character that is not a `-`.

Comment: Thank you very much and what does "more than zero" means? I think the meaning of + in `[A-Za-z-]+` ?

Comment: @LukášAltman `+` modifies the meaning of the previous expression. It modifies so that it must match at least once (but possibly more).  `.+` would match _one or more characters_. This is similar to `*`, but `*` matches _zero_ or more times. Hence, `.*` would match zero or more characters.  Without the `+` in the expression in my answer, the expression would only ever match a _single_ character, not a word with possible hyphens.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understant. I added a picture to my question what I tried. It is not a good example?

Comment: @LukášAltman See updated answer.  It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you. I have no achievement. I only read a manual and I had a problem with this part. I thought `^` means the start of line. So it's not start? It should be before [] to mean start of line? What is an example to see the difference between `[Y-Zy-z-]+` and  `[Y-Zy-z-]` ?

Comment: @LukášAltman `^` means the start of the line, but within `[...]` it negates the character class.  If you want all lines that starts with a non-dash, you would use `^[^-]` (in your example data, this would probably be all lines).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89838/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-kusalananda).